# HTML/CSS - проблема при вёрстке баннера

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Всем привет!
Мне нужно сверстать страницу. Проблема в том, что не отображается корректно банер. Если просматриваю свою страницу офлайн на своём узле, то всё ОК. А когда загружаю её на хостинг, то в браузере банер вообще исчезает, хотя если зайти на страницу со-смартфона, она отображается правильно, вместе с баннером.

Баннер я создал шириной 1024-pix, после чего раскроил его на 3-части. При этом левую и правую часть задаю в HTML-паге с фиксированным размером в пикселях (в них имеется лого), а середину оставил под чистый фон и делаю его резиновым в процентах. Таким образом адаптировал для мин.клиента 1024-pix, а если больше, то середина должна растягиваться. Как уже говорил, в смартфонах и на моём узле это работает, но в браузере компа через хост нет. В чём может быть проблема?

На данный момент я запихал три картинки банера в таблицу, хотя пробовал и через блоки DIV, но безрезультатно - не хватает знаний и правая часть в 374-pix постоянно съезжает на новую/нижнюю строку. Может через стили CSS блоки можно/нужно зафиксировать? Вот моя текущая табличка HTML. Заранее благодарю за советы:

```
<table width='100%' cellspacing='0' cellpadding="0">
<tr>
    <td width="586"><img src="img/baner/Main_01.png"></td>
    <td width="100%" background="img/baner/Main_02.png"></td>
    <td width="374"><img src="img/baner/Main_03.png"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Вот второй/блочный вариант, он не работает как нужно - при разрешении 1280px середина не растягивается на всю страницу. Но и здесь при загрузки страницы на хост браузер не отображает баннер, а в смартфоне - нормально:

CSS:

```
.baner .lfcol {
    width           : 586px;
    float           : left;
    padding-top     : 0px;
    border          : 0px;
    overflow        : hidden;
    }
.baner .ctcol {
    float           : left;
    padding-top     : 0px;
    border          : 0px;
    background-image: url(img/baner/Main2_02.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    overflow        : inherit;
    }
.baner .rhcol {
    width           : 374px;
    float           : right;
    padding-top     : 0px;
    border          : 0px;
    overflow        : hidden;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="baner">
    <div class="lfcol"><img src="img/baner/Main2_01.png"></div>
    <div class="ctcol">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="rhcol"><img src="img/baner/Main2_03.png"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Возьмите обычный inkscape, нарисуйте в нём и всё ...банер станет резиновым...и отображаться будет везде

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю такой вариант, сделать на flex.

```css
.lfcol {
    width           : 586px;
    overflow        : hidden;
    }
.ctcol {
    background-image: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/01/12/10/19/fantasy-3077928__340.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;  
    width: 100%;
    }
.rhcol {
    width           : 374px;
    overflow        : hidden;

}
.baner {
    display: flex;
    height: 335px;
    width: 100%;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="baner">
    <div class="lfcol"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/12/01/20/28/road-1072821__340.jpg"></div>
    <div class="ctcol">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="rhcol"><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/09/21/04/46/barley-field-1684052__340.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Александр, опять у меня в браузере код работает вроде нормально, но если выложить на хост, то средняя картинка вообще исчезает, а правая переходит на сл.строку и оказывается внизу. Причем на смартфоне тоже так-же.

Comment: Можно ссылку на файлы на вашем хосте? И что у Вас за хостинг ?

Comment: У вас  в данный момент на картинках стоит css  свойство 
display: none !important;
Поэтому в данный момент они скрыты

Comment: Не понял... где стоит это свойство, в моём файле стилей `style.css` что-ли? Если да, то в нём лежит как вы указали `display: flex;`

Comment: Вы мне скинули ссылку на 3 изображения (Main2_01.png, Main2_02.png, Main2_031.png) - я их открыл и  в стилях стоит такое свойство display: none !important;
Вот скрин https://pastenow.ru/5c034b8ad71934df7ed95e77787f1519

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136613/discussion-between--and-prodigy).

Comment: Оказывается всё работает и проблема исключительно с браузером Chrome (у меня последняя ver.100). Если захожу на страницу с лисы или MS-Edge, то баннер отображается. Буду искать, что не нравится именно хрому.